# Java 8 Apply a BiFunction to two lists of different objects

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I need to know how I can apply a `BiFunction` to two lists of different objects

```
List<A> listA;
List<B> listB;

private BiFunction<A,B,C> biFunction=new BiFunction<A,B,C>() {
    @Override
    public C apply(A a, B b) {
        C c=new C();

        return c;
    }
};
```

I need to get a `List<C>` and for that I have to use `biFunction` with `listA` and `listB`.
I do not know how to do this in Java 8, the only way I know is this:

```
List<C> listC=new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0;i<listA.size();i++)
            listC.add(biFunction.apply(listA.get(i),listB.get(i)));
```

Obviously `listA` and `listB` have the same size.
It's a horrible solution, please can you suggest a better way?

Comment: I don't believe a better solution exists without using external libraries.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know, the cleanliest way without using external libraries is this:

```
List<A> listA;
List<B> listB;

BiFunction<A, B, C> biFunction = (a, b) -> {
    C c = new C();
    return c;
};

List<C> listC = IntStream.range(0, listA.size())
        .mapToObj(i -> biFunction.apply(listA.get(i), listB.get(i)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`StreamUtils`](https://github.com/poetix/protonpack/blob/master/src/main/java/com/codepoetics/protonpack/StreamUtils.java) from `protonpack`:

```
Stream<C> streamC = StreamUtils.zip(listA, listB, biFunction);
```

It is open source so don't hesitate to give it a look.

Comment: `StreamUtils.zip` does not zip lists, it zips streams, so you should use it like `StreamUtils.zip(listA.stream(), listB.stream(), biFunction)`. Also it should be noted that unlike @HelderPereira solution this version is not parallel-friendly.